# Open Image Gallery (Photo Album) Application in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, url

How to open Image Gallery (Android) or Photo Album (iOS) in Flutter. I don't want to pick an image from the image gallery. What I want is to open the image gallery application programmatically.

I tried to search Flutter open image gallery application. All of the results are teaching me how to use image_picker package. But what is not what I want.

I have tried to use url_launcher package. This is what I have tried (it seemed to work on iOS but I am not sure if it is appropriate):

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  String _url = "photos-redirect://";
  if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
    launch(_url);
  }
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // To DO
}
```

Comment: This is in fact the correct approach. You can also use the [android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) package specifically for Android.

Comment: For android_intent_plus package, what is the url for image gallery?

Comment: I have provided an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is appropriate for iOS. For Android, you can use the [android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus/example) plugin.

```
const intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'action_view',
  type: 'image/*',
  flags: [Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK],
);
intent.launch();
```

Comment: it says "unsupported file" while also succesfully launch the gallery app. any idea why?

Comment: are you creating the intent exactly as shown here or passing extra data?

Comment: exactly as shown, no extra data passed

Comment: No clue. Just ran on Android 11 & 13 and did not see this behavior. What device/Android version or you testing on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) plugin. It supports both Android and IOS.

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open(${imagePath});
```